# Heroku Apollo Server throws "ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" only for some queries

Tags: heroku, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I created a GraphQL wrapper for [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/). My queries all work in development fine and most of them work in production. However, I have the following query that works in production for smaller `start` and `end` ranges, but throws `"ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"` when I try to query for all of the pokemon with a very large range. This error does not happen in development.

```
query {
    allPokemon(start: 0, end: 964) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

My resolver in my GraphQL for `allPokemon` only hits one REST endpoint and comes back with an array of objects that have the following structure:

```
{
  name: "charmander",
  url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"
}
```

My resolver maps over the resulting array to grab the `name` value and to parse the `url` value to grab the id number at the end of the string.

Not sure if this is relevant/necessary to include here, but I am using `apollo-datasource-rest`. I created a class component that extends `RESTDataSource` that has abstracted out my functions for my GraphQL resolvers. Then I simply call those methods inside of my resolvers. My `allPokemon` method inside this `RESTDataSource` component looks like this:

```
async getAllPokemon(start = 0, end = 964) {
        const response = await this.get(`pokemon?offset=${start}&limit=${end}`);

        const pokemonIds = response.results.map(pokemon =>
            parseUrl(pokemon.url)
        );

        return pokemonIds;
    }
```

`parseUrl` is a utils function I created that just takes a url and parses it to grab the number at the end of the url after the last `/`.

Then in my resolvers, I have the following:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allPokemon: (parent, args, { dataSources }) => {
            return dataSources.pokemonAPI.getAllPokemon(args.start, args.end);
        }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out if this is an issue with Heroku or with Apollo Server. My guess was with Heroku since I have no problems in development getting the expected data for all of the queries. I thought perhaps Heroku must have some limitations as far as timing out or how how many iterations of the parsing function it can do, but have been unable to confirm this theory, let alone find a solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If your application takes more than 30 seconds to process the request, Heroku *will* throw a timeout error.

Comment: Wouldn't it throw a timeout error though? Instead of a ServerParseError?

Comment: Is that error coming from your server? Normally that's just what ApolloClient throws when it fails to parse a response.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's coming from the server...this is the error "stack" it gives me: 
```
"ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at /Users/janessagarrow/Dev/pokedex-pokeapi-graphql/node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/lib/index.js:35:25",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
```
I'm not sure why it's timing out though because it throws the error after 18 seconds